# is there a movie recording tool for dslr connected to phones?

Tags: dslr

I have a 40D and I'm sometimes using EOS-MovRec to record movies. Since there is no firmware mod/hack for the 40d available I'm asking this question.

Is there a tool for the iphone/symbian/android to connect my DSLR and use it just like in
EOS-MovRec as a camera and record a movie?

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

Try this link you will get some tips
http://dpexperience.com/2010/02/12/recording-audio-with-your-video-dslr-part-i/